# implement a global configure in Python

Tags: python

I want to write a script which will do some specific job, each time when the job is done, I want to increase a `job_done_count` by 1, that is if I run the script 10 times, `job_done_count` will be `10`.

This is how this script looks like,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

job_done_count = 0   
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_the_job()
    job_done_count += 1
```

I kind wonder it works or not. Because, each time I run the script, `job_done_count` will be set to 0, then 1. It doesn't remember how many times the job being done at all.

Am I supposed not to put this `job_done_count` in the script?

Comment: you can use [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) to save `job_done_count` to a file and restoring it at each run

Comment: So, if I put `job_done_count` in the script, then I won't get the correct value anyway.

Comment: Why? You first get it from a file and then save it to the file. Why would it be incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or don't use pickle and do it in any of the following ways.

By hand

```
with open("jobs_done.txt") as inp:
    job_done_count = int(inp.read().strip())
```

With [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)

```
with open("jobs_done.json") as inp:
    job_done_count = json.load(inp)['jobs_done']
```

Or with a billion other methods!

Comment: A billion methods might be overestimating a little. ;-)

Comment: What about xml? :) I agree using pickle is overkill here and results in a file that is not easy to examine from other languages.

Answer (score 3):

You can [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) the `job_done_count` variable into a file:

```py
import os, pickle

if os.path.exists('job_count.pickle'):
    with open('job_count.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
        job_done_count = pickle.load(handle)
else:
    job_done_count = 0

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_the_job()
    job_done_count += 1

    with open('job_count.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
        pickle.dump(job_done_count, handle)
```

Comment: You might like to increment `job_done_count` before saving the pickle.

Comment: For a simple integer like that you really don't need to bother with pickling it. Just write it to the file with `handler.write(str(job_done_count))`, and restore with `int(handle.read())`. Much simpler, and any other program can also read and write the file.

Comment: The two solutions only differ by a few characters. I prefer `pickle` because `job_done_count` can be replaced with almost any other Python object and the code will still work perfectly fine.